# Getting a USB camera picture within a program

Tags: c#, c++, camera

I would like to get a picture from the camera (USB generally) so as to do some processing after that. I have already managed to do that with OpenCV so I am looking for a method that does not use that.

I have read some methods to do that last year but would like to put this in order so please correct me if I am wrong (as I am writing now by heart)

As for platforms and languages I am quite open (I work in windows, but can also get a Mac or a linux machine) (And for languages, I prefer anything C-related. say C++ , C# or another, but would be happy to learn about python approaches)

I actually made this [yet another camera control](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/330177/yet-another-web-camera-control?msg=5303854#xx5303854xx) work in my pc last year, but wow it seems a rather complicated structure.. is this the minimum required in windows?

Any comment advice or pointer very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**If you** are looking for documentation in C++ you can visit this website .
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/193519-win32-webcam-program/

**Note : I don't know if you've seen it before .**

The process is pretty simple . Create a Win32 window , and then link the window to the camera .

```
camhwnd = capCreateCaptureWindow ("camera window", WS_CHILD , 0,     100,300,300, hwnd, 0);
SendMessage(camhwnd,WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT,0,0);
SendMessage(camhwnd,WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEOSOURCE,0,0);
........
SendMessage(camhwnd, WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME, 0, 0);
//Copy the frame we have just grabbed to the clipboard
SendMessage(camhwnd, WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY,0,0);
```

Comment: Thanks. It is said there that it uses Video for Windows. But I have heard also that Vfw is pretty old and deprecated... is this so?